# Laravel Left Join Query

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.3 and I have some left join query with error in laravel query method. 
This is my normal query

```
 SELECT bran.branchName,sch.schoolName From m_schoolbranch bran
LEFT JOIN m_students stu ON stu.schoolNo=bran.schoolNo AND stu.branchNo=bran.branchNo  
LEFT JOIN m_school sch ON sch.schoolNo=stu.schoolNo where stu.userNo='0000000001';
```

And this is my new laravel Query

```
DB::table('m_schoolbranch')
            ->join('m_students', 'm_schoolbranch.schoolNo', '=', 'm_students.schoolNo')
            ->join('m_students', 'm_schoolbranch.branchNo', '=', 'm_students.branchNo')
            ->join('m_school', 'm_schoolbranch.schoolNo', '=', 'm_school.schoolNo')
            ->select('m_school.schoolName', 'm_schoolbranch.branchName')
            ->where('m_students.userNo',$userNo)
            ->get();
```

In these query I need to match two column in table m_students  so I put like this

```
->join('m_students', 'm_schoolbranch.branchNo', '=', 'm_students.branchNo')
```

But i show error...

Comment: What does error say?

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'm_students' (SQL: select `m_school`.`schoolName`, `m_schoolbranch`.`branchName` from `m_schoolbranch` inner join `m_students` on `m_schoolbranch`.`schoolNo` = `m_students`.`schoolNo` inner join `m_students` on `m_schoolbranch`.`branchNo` = `m_students`.`branchNo` inner join `m_school` on `m_schoolbranch`.`schoolNo` = `m_school`.`schoolNo` where `m_students`.`userNo` = 0000000001)

Answer (score 0):

Tables in the query need to have unique names, otherwise the DB has no way of knowing which `m_schoolbranch` should be used when evaluating `m_schoolbranch.schoolNo`.

You could use unique table aliases in your join statements but I recommend using multiple conditions on the join. Just like you use in your original SQL query. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20732468/4437888

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('m_schoolbranch')
            ->join('m_students', function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('m_schoolbranch.schoolNo', '=', 'm_students.schoolNo');
                    $join->on('m_schoolbranch.branchNo', '=', 'm_students.branchNo');
                })
            ->join('m_school', 'm_schoolbranch.schoolNo', '=', 'm_school.schoolNo')
            ->select('m_school.schoolName', 'm_schoolbranch.branchName')
            ->where('m_students.userNo',$userNo)
            ->get();
```