# Use `AND` in Laravel Query Builder, syntax error (orOn)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this sql (MariaDB) query, it works ok:

```
SELECT
    admin_combustibles.nombre,
    admin_combustibles.id_combustible,
    admin_combustible_unidades.nombre AS unidades,
    admin_tipo_combustibles.nombre AS tipo_combustible,
    admin_indice_combustibles.valor_combustible
FROM
    admin_combustibles
INNER JOIN admin_combustible_unidades ON admin_combustibles.combustible_unidades_id = admin_combustible_unidades.id_combustible_unidad
INNER JOIN admin_tipo_combustibles ON admin_combustibles.tipo_combustible_id = admin_tipo_combustibles.id_tipo_combustible
LEFT  JOIN admin_indice_combustibles ON admin_combustibles.id_combustible = admin_indice_combustibles.combustible_id
AND admin_indice_combustibles.anio = 1992
AND admin_indice_combustibles.mes = 6
ORDER BY
    admin_combustibles.nombre
```

But when I try to make it through Laravel, I have some error because Laravel put some  on the number 1992, in that way the query doesn't work.

Plus, I don't know how to do the `AND` on Laravel, I only have `orOn` but it doesn't work:

```
$datos = AdminCombustible::select([
    'admin_combustibles.nombre',
    'admin_combustibles.id_combustible',
    'admin_combustible_unidades.nombre AS unidades',
    'admin_tipo_combustibles.nombre AS tipo_combustible',
    'admin_indice_combustibles.valor_combustible'])
    ->join('admin_combustible_unidades', 'admin_combustibles.combustible_unidades_id', '=', 'admin_combustible_unidades.id_combustible_unidad')
    ->join('admin_tipo_combustibles', 'admin_combustibles.tipo_combustible_id', '=', 'admin_tipo_combustibles.id_tipo_combustible')

    ->leftJoin('admin_indice_combustibles', function ($join) {
        $join->on('admin_indice_combustibles.combustible_id', '=', 'admin_combustibles.id_combustible')->orOn('admin_indice_combustibles.anio', '=', 1992);
    })
    ->get();
    dd($datos);
```

I got an sql syntax error.

Any help on how to make that query with query builder of Laravel? (I put the entire query as DB::raw and it works, but I don't want to use raw() )

Comment: This could help - [Laravel Eloquent inner join with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38695821/3226121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there might be two problems here.  Since you are using `and` in your original query, you might be needing to use `or` instead of `orOn` on your join.

Also you will need to use `DB::raw()` on the parameters, otherwise Laravel will consider them columns....

```
$join->on('admin_indice_combustibles.combustible_id', '=', 'admin_combustibles.id_combustible')->on('admin_indice_combustibles.anio', '=', DB::raw('1992'));
```